# Using if else statement in MQL5 with "="

Tags: if-statement, mql5

I was wondering if something like this could work. Can you assign a value to something with 'if' 'else'? So in the code I used = and if else with each other, could this work?

```
void OnTick()
  {
   int      UMA = if (close>open)
                  {high-close};
                  else
                  {high-open};
                                   
   int      LMA = if (close>open) 
                  {low-open}; 
                  else
                  {low-close};  
    
   int      UMA1 = if (close>open)
                  {close+UMAX}; 
                  else
                  {open+UMAX};       
   
   int      LMA1 = if (close>open)
                  {open+LMAX}; 
                  else
                  {close+LMAX};
//---

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use [if else](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/basis/operators/if) statement like that in MQL5. Your code would need rearranging as follows.

```
void OnTick()
{
   int UMA, LMA, UMA1, LMA1;
   if(close>open) UMA=high-close; else UMA=high-open;
   if(close>open) LMA=low-open; else LMA=low-close;
   if(close>open) UMA1=close+UMAX; else UMA1=open+UMAX;
   if(close>open) LMA1=open+LMAX; else LMA1=close+LMAX;
}
```

The above is set out as your code, but this could be further improved as follows.

```
void OnTick()
{
   int UMA, LMA, UMA1, LMA1;
   if(close>open) {UMA=high-close; LMA=low-open; UMA1=close+UMAX; LMA1=open+LMAX;}
   else {UMA=high-open; LMA=low-close; UMA1=open+UMAX; LMA1=close+LMAX;}
}
```